# Circular reference caused by alias "Expr1"

Tags: sql, ms-access

Look at the following code, and suggest where I could be going wrong.

```sql
SELECT
    Table2.[Mover name],
    Table2.Lead_Type,
    Count(Table2.[Lead_Type]) AS Total_Leads,
    [Total_Charges] AS Expr1
FROM
    Table2
GROUP BY
    Table2.[Mover name],
    Table2.Lead_Type
HAVING
    ((([Total_Charges])=IIf([Table2]![Lead_Type]="Intenrational (2)",
                            [Table2]![Quoted price]*[Table2]![movesouq_charge],
                            IIf([Table2]![Lead_Type]="International car",
                                [Table2]!  [Quoted price]*[Table2]![movesouq_charge],
                                [Query2]![Expr1]*[Table2]![movesouq_charge]
                               )
                           )
    ));
```

When I try to run this query, an error is generated 'Circular reference caused by alias Expr1 in query definition's Select List.'

Comment: This is tagged as VBA - what language are you using here?

Comment: You are referring to a `Query2` which is not part of the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have expr1 as an alias for Total_Charges and as part of query2's name in your having clause.

In addition, you have a spelling mistake in your iif statement: IIf([Table2]![Lead_Type]="**Intenrational** (2)"